# Calling Data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, foreign-keys

I am kind of new to SQL. I have 2 MySQL Tables. Below is their structure.

**`Key_Hash` Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `key_hash` (
 `primary_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hash` text NOT NULL,
 `totalNumberOfWords` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

--

**`Key_Word` Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `key_word` (
 `primary_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `indexVal` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hashed_word` char(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`),
 KEY `hashed_word` (`hashed_word`,`indexVal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28570982 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now, below is my query

```
SELECT `indexVal`, COUNT(`indexVal`) FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word` IN ('001','01v') GROUP BY `indexVal` LIMIT 100;
```

When you run the above query, you will get an output like below

[image]

The important thing here to note is that `indexVal` in `key_word` table is the same set of data in `primary_key` in `key_hash` table (I think it can be a foreign key?). In other words, `primary_key` data in `key_hash` table appear as `indexVal` in `key_word` table. But pleas note  `indexVal` can appear any number of times inside the table because it is not a primary key in `key_word`.

OK so, this is not the query what I need exactly. I need to count how many times each unique `indexVal` appear in the above search, and divide it by appropriate value in `key_hash.totalNumberOfWords`.

***I am providing few examples below.***

Imagine I ran the above query, now the result is generated. It says

- `indexVal` 0 appeared 10 times in search
- `indexVal` 1 appeared 20 times in search
- `indexVal` 300 appeared 20,000 times in search

Now keep in mind that `key_hash.primary_key` = `key_word.indexVal` . first I search for `key_hash.primary_key` which is similar to `key_word.indexVal` and get the associated `key_hash.numberOfWords`. Then I divide the `count()` appeared in the above mentioned query from this `key_hash.numberOfWords` and multiply the total answer by 100 (to get the value as a percentage). Below is a query I tried but it has errors.

```
  SELECT `indexVal`,COUNT(`indexVal`), (COUNT(`indexVal`) / (select `numberOfWords` from `key_hash` where `primary_key`=`key_word.indexVal`)*100) FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word` IN ('001','01v') GROUP BY `indexVal` LIMIT 100;
```

How can I do this job?

**EDIT**

This is how the `key_hash` table looks like

[image]

This is how the `key_word` table looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN instead of a sub-query

```
SELECT w.indexVal
     , COUNT(w.indexVal)
     , COUNT(w.indexVal) / MAX(h.numberOfWords) * 100
FROM   key_word w
       INNER JOIN key_hash h ON h.primary_key = w.indexVal
WHERE  w.hashed_word IN ('001','01v') 
GROUP BY indexVal 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Or possibly SUM(h.numberOfWords).  Hard to tell without data example from both tables.

Comment: True.  Or the group by has GROUP BY indexVal`,`key_hash`.`primary_key`

Comment: @SQLDBA: Data samples added. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Serpiton: Thanks for the reply. But it is giving me errors. and what does that `MAX(h.numberOfWords)` supposed to do?

Comment: The error is ` Unknown column 'h.numberOfWords' in 'field list' `